# Image Highlight and Brightness on hover

Tags: html, css

I have created an image gallery and every time I hover over one I want a white overlay to show that the image is being hovered on however I would not want to lose the quality of the image.I have already tried changing the opacity but I want it to start with a 100% opacity and then increase.However, this is not possible so I would like a highlight over the image without decreasing the quality.

Here is the link to my work:

http://www.mediafire.com/file/g1yagf1u6y7ea67/website%204.zip

Is there any way in CSS or HTML to do this?

Comment: Hi Hamza. Please do not use file lockers here for your work. We need the question material to be in the question itself, so that we do not have to repair the question if the link breaks in the future. Good questions do not need file lockers at all, since if a locker is required, it probably contains too much code to avoid being Too Broad (an official close reason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CSS filter property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp).

```
.your-image:hover {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.15);   
}
```